# Simple jQuery stylesheet swaper

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to create a swapper at website. I have one link, and I would like to swap between two .css files on each click on it. After first click I see that classes and files are swaping, but after second click nothing happens at all...

Call:

```
<a href="#" id="swaper" class="ozn color_ozn" >SWAP</a>
```

jQuery code:

```
google.load("jquery", "1.3.1");
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    $(".color_ozn").click(function(){
        $("link").attr("href", "link_to_style1.css");
        $("#swaper").removeClass("color_ozn");
        $("#swaper").addClass("color");
        return false;
    });

    $(".color").click(function(){
        $("link").attr("href", "link_to_style2.css");
        $("#swaper").removeClass("color");
        $("#swaper").addClass("color_ozn");
        return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are swapping classes dynamically, you have to use [**`event delegation`**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) in this context to achieve what you want.

Try,

```
$('body').on('click',".color_ozn",function(){
    $("link").attr("href", "link_to_style1.css");
    $("#swaper").removeClass("color_ozn");
    $("#swaper").addClass("color");
    return false;
});
```

and

```
$('body').on('click',".color",function(){
    $("link").attr("href", "link_to_style2.css");
    $("#swaper").removeClass("color");
    $("#swaper").addClass("color_ozn");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rajaprabhu :) I also had to change jQuery version to higher, because (as someone at stackoverflow mentioned) .on method was introduced in 1.7 release.